# Move scrollbar to the bottom of the page in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, scrolling

I am trying to display the scroll bar at the bottom of the page instead of displaying at the top of the page along with the data for an LWC component. Similar to mobile device, this is what I have

```
   <div class="slds-scrollable_y" >                                                          
       <template for:each={data} for:item="data">       
           <div key={data.Id}>
               <c-child-component data={data}></c-child-component>                        
           </div>
        </template>
     </div>
```

which tags can I use in CSS to display the scrollbar at the bottom of the div just like texting from phone the scrollbar starts at bottom?

Comment: Do you want to scroll to the bottom on load, or are you trying to physically move the scrollbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to use scrollTop/scrollHeight in a script. Here's an example:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  data = [...Array(100).keys()].map(value => ({Id: value, value: `Message ${value}`}));
  renderedCallback() {
    const scrollArea = this.template.querySelector('[data-scroll-area]')
    scrollArea.scrollTop = scrollArea.scrollHeight
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/AAwLtEdIedXtZefHoVmM/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: You are genious @Sfdcfox, I just have to make one small change, just run a null check on the scrollArea and that's all, it worked!!! Thanks a ton again!!